# Setting cookie path and domain (Rails 6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, cookies

Does anyone have experience/advice on setting the cookie path and domain, for security hardening in a Rails 6 app?

The [Rails docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) show setting the path and domain, but it's not clear to me in practice where to do this, or what to set them to (well the domain is obvious I suppose).

By default the cookie path is set to `"/"`. [owasp.org](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/latest/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/06-Session_Management_Testing/02-Testing_for_Cookies_Attributes) describes this vulnerability:

> The Path attribute plays a major role in setting the scope of the
> cookies in conjunction with the domain. In addition to the domain, the
> URL path that the cookie is valid for can be specified. If the domain
> and path match, then the cookie will be sent in the request. Just as
> with the domain attribute, if the path attribute is set too loosely,
> then it could leave the application vulnerable to attacks by other
> applications on the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safer to not specify the domain attribute of the cookie. A cookie without a domain attribute will only be sent to the original host (e.g. example.com). On the other hand, a cookie with domain=example.com will be sent to example.com as well as its subdomains (sub.example.com, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), etc.). In other words, if the domain attribute is not specified, the range in which cookies are sent is narrower.

The path attribute of the cookie may be specified, but it does not have much security effect. For example, a cookie with path=/mypage will not be sent to https://example.com/about, but if you send a request from this page to https://example.com/mypage with XMLHttpRequest, the following will occur The cookie with path=/mypage will be given to the request. Even if the cookie itself is not stolen due to the httponly attribute, the response from https://example.com/mypage will be retrieved by the attacker. As a result, your personal information will be stolen.

In conclusion, it is safer not to add the domain attribute to the cookie, and the path attribute, although it can be added, has little security effect.

Comment: Thanks. Would you say the owasp.org wording about the vulnerability is a bit misleading/overblown?

Comment: Yes, I think the owasp.org wording is misleading.